# Issue with Laravel Valet and SSL certificate conflict on external domain

Tags: networking, dns, ssl-certificate, laravel-valet

I'm currently facing a peculiar issue while using Laravel Valet for local web development (system: macOS Monterey 12.7.1). My local websites are running smoothly with Valet, but I've encountered a strange problem with an external website.

For some reason, when I try to access this external site, it seems to be using the SSL certificate from one of my local websites hosted through Valet. This is quite surprising as I would expect this external domain to use its own certificate and not one from my local setup.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Restart Valet, router and computer.
- Cleared browser and DNS cache.
- Checked the hosts file for any incorrect entries (which were fine).The issue persists across all browsers but resolves when I switch to my mobile phone network, suggesting it's specific to my local computer's configuration.
- Traceroute results indicated that the external website was resolving to 127.0.0.1.
- My hosts file and Valet configuration seem standard, focusing on
  .test domains. I also checked the Dnsmasq configurations used by
  Valet, which looked normal.

I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced a similar issue or might have insights into what could be causing this.

Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated. These DNS issues are really not my strongest suit.